# Is it possible to send images,videos,sounds etc using microsoft push notification in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am making use of windows push notification service. When i pass a notification message to microsoft push notification service, can i pass audio or video along with the message? Is it necessary that the payload contain only text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put pretty much everything you want in the notification's payload, but the size cannot exceed 3KB. Therefore, you should rather host the content somewhere, send the URL with the notification, and let the client download it.

Comment: Yes, and obviosuly this only makes sense with regards a raw notification